# The name "svar" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I'm very new to programming and I am writing a short hangman game for my programming class, I have two private voids, one when you change the text in the textbox for the correct answer and one for when you guess a character. I need to transfer the variable "svar" from the first instance to the other, when I try to use the variable "svar" in the second instance I get the error message "The name "svar" does not exist in the current context"

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {      
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TbxSvar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbxSvar.TextLength == 6)
            {
                pbxGubbe.Top = 6;
                tbxVisa.Text = "??????";
                tbxGissa.Enabled = true;
                string svar = tbxSvar.Text;
                tbxSvar.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {

                tbxVisa.Text = "";
            }

        }

        private void TbxGissa_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbxGissa.Text == "") return;
            string gissning = tbxGissa.Text;
            int index = svar.indexOf(gissning);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should read about fields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields

Comment: And similarly, that 'int  index' is gone when you leave that TxbGissa_TextChanged method

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `svar` as a variable in a method so it won't be visible elsewhere (unless you pass it as a method argument).  Instead define it as a *field* in your class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {      
        string svar;  // <----------- place here.  Now it is a 'field'

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TbxSvar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbxSvar.TextLength == 6)
            {
                pbxGubbe.Top = 6;
                tbxVisa.Text = "??????";
                tbxGissa.Enabled = true;
                svar = tbxSvar.Text;  // <---------- use svar here
                tbxSvar.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {

                tbxVisa.Text = "";
            }

        }

        private void TbxGissa_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbxGissa.Text == "") return;
            string gissning = tbxGissa.Text;
            int index = svar.indexOf(gissning); // <---------- ...and here

        }
    }
```

Comment: When I do that the svar variable gets treated like two variables or something, I used a breakpoint to see if my variable svar inside the if statement had a value, it got assigned the value of the textbox like expected but when the variable was called in the second instance the value was null, EDIT: Nevermind, I fixed it. Thanks